# How to insert "Author" code in Wordpress Required theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

Been trying to insert "By Author" `by <?php the_author() ?>` code on a Wordpress theme(Required by 8Bit). Request to help. Need to insert after the post/page title and before date.

The code is as follows:

```
<header>
    <?php if ( 0 < strlen( get_the_title() ) ) { ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h1><!-- /.entry-title --> 
    <?php } // end if ?>

    <div class="post-meta">
        <span class="post-date">
            <?php if ( 0 < strlen( get_the_title() ) ) { ?>
                <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ));?>
                </a>
            <?php } // end if/else ?>
        </span><!-- /.post-date -->
        <?php _e( ' | ', 'required' ); ?>
        <span class="comment-link">
            <?php 
                comments_popup_link( 'Comment', '1 comment', '% comments',
                    'comments-link', '');
            ?>
        </span><!-- /.comment-link -->
        <?php edit_post_link( '- edit ', '<span>', '</span>'); ?>
    </div><!-- /.post-meta -->
</header>
```

Thanks :)

This is the loop code:

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) {

            while ( have_posts() ) {


                                   the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            } // end while
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you tried and what went wrong? From my point of few it could be as simple as inserting the `<?php the_author() ?>` between the title block and the `post-meta` block, and adding some HTML for formatting...

Comment: where is the  `by <?php the_author() ?>` in your code ?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt  Thanks for replying. Yes, I tried that, it didn't work. If possible, can you insert the code and comment out next time when you reply.

Comment: @wordpresser  There is no <?php the_author() ?> in the code. I want to insert it between the given codes. The "author code" should come between the title and before the date. Can you help? Thanks for replying.

Comment: `the_Author()` function can only be used inside a loop, where r u using it ?.. other thing is can you post the whole of your post including the loop

Comment: @wordpresser  Have included the loop code from single.php. As far as I know, I don't think anything can be included there. It's the content.php part which matters[which I have posted in the question].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, between the title and date:

```
<header>
    <?php if ( 0 < strlen( get_the_title() ) ) { ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h1><!-- /.entry-title --> 
    <?php } // end if ?>

    <div class="post-meta">
    <?php the_author(); ?>
        <span class="post-date">
            <?php if ( 0 < strlen( get_the_title() ) ) { ?>
                <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ));?>
                </a>
            <?php } // end if/else ?>
        </span><!-- /.post-date -->
        <?php _e( ' | ', 'required' ); ?>
        <span class="comment-link">
            <?php 
                comments_popup_link( 'Comment', '1 comment', '% comments',
                    'comments-link', '');
            ?>
        </span><!-- /.comment-link -->
        <?php edit_post_link( '- edit ', '<span>', '</span>'); ?>
    </div><!-- /.post-meta -->
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you @jerdiggity . There were many if/else statements in the code. I was focusing on only one part of the code that's why it didn't work earlier. After confirming from you I tested it in each and every conditions one by one. It worked :)

Comment: I really searched a lot how to post author name in header but never found a simple and working solution but yours : <?php the_author(); ?>